# Concept of an Equivalence class partition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The definition:

Part 1:
The equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on a set S constitute a partition of S. 
Part2:
Conversely, for any partition of S, there is an equivalence relation on S whose equivalence classes are the element of p.

To make sure I'm not blundering over the definition, let's suppose
a and b are integers in the set S.
The equivalence class of $a$ is given as:
$$[a]=\{a+kn|k \in S\}$$

We have that:
$$[1]=\{\dots,(-1-kn),(-1-(k+1)n),\dots,(1+kn),(1+(k+1)n),\dots\}$$
and where a takes on discrete values, we have equivalence classes that forms a partition on a set S.

The partition is: $$[1],[2],[3],....$$

This concludes my understanding of the first part.

Is my understanding correct?

Could someone also shed some light on the second part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example.
Take the integers, and consider this equivalence relation:
A is equivalent to b if they differ by three or a multiple of three.
So, we have
[1]={..., -5, -2, 1, 4, 7, ...}
[2]={..., -4, -1, 2, 5, 8, ...}
[3]={..., -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, ...}

These are the only three classes of this relation.
Every integer appears in exactly one class.
Any element of a class can be taken as its representative ([3]=[0]).

Every equivalence relation works like this: it divides a set in "slices" that don't overlap, and cover the entire set. That is to say, a partition.

Second part: if you already have a partition, you can find an equivalence relation with that partition. Just take something equivalent to "x and y are in the same slice"!

Answer (score 1):

The partition claimed in your statement is correct iff the different $[i],[j]$ are all distinct.

I suggest you refrain from examples and remain on the mere abstract level:

The equivalence classes determine a partition of $S$ because any element of $S$ is contained in an equivalence class, and two equivalence classes are either disjoint or equal, due to the definition of equivalence relation.

On the other hand, given a partition, you can define an equivalence relation by setting any two elements in the same portion of the partition to be equivalent, and **not** equivalent if they lie in different component. You can easily verify that this defines an equivalence relation.

For the second paragraph: Assume your set $S$ admits a partition $S= \bigsqcup_{i\in I} P_i$. Then for any two elements $s_1,s_2\in S$ you **define** $s_1\sim s_2 :\iff \exists \ i\in I \ s.t. s_1,s_2\in P_i$. Now you can show that this defines an equivalence relation which conversely defines your partition you started with.

Comment: You mentioned 'disjoint or equal'. What is the definition of 'equal' in this context?
I do not understand the last paragraph.
A little more intuitive explanation would help.

Comment: In the set-theoretic sense: they contain the same elements. See my edit